# rapi.dll problem in windows 7 - C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-7

i work with OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.dll (RAPI) to connect

between PC and Windows mobile in my C# program.

in Windows xp it work's excellent, but in windows 7 i get this error:

Unable to load DLL 'rapi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

in windows xp i install ActiveSync but in windows 7 i know that he is build in

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a stupid answer, but did you install WMDC (Windows Mobile Device Center) on your Win7 PC?  WMDC is the equivalent of ActiveSync on WinXP, and it will install the RAPI.DLL file.

Regards,
Henk

Answer (score 0):

To debug DLL problems, use Dependency Walker (depends.exe). It can do both static and dynamic analysis of DLL dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As Henk van Asselt said. 
Installing **Windows Mobie Device Center** should solve problem.
You can also look for **rapi.dll** file in:
**C:\Windows\System32**

Comment: This should just be a comment on Henk van Asselt's answer.

Comment: Yes of course I fully agree with you but:
"You must have 50 reputation to comment"