# C# dll problem in windows 7

Tags: c#, dll, windows-7-x64

I'm having exactly the same problem as the poster in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741473/rapi-dll-problem-in-windows-7-c). I have a visual studio C# projects from which I'm trying to call a function in another DLL (which is also part of the solution).

The DLL is a C++ one and the exported function I'm trying to call is declared like this in C#:

```
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
private extern static IntPtr SomeFunction(IntPtr someVar1, IntPtr someVar2, bool someVar3);
```

When I try to call the function from C# I see the following on the console output in the debugger:

> 'MyApp.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\SomePath\Build\Eddy\Debug\SomeDLL.dll'
>   'MyApp.exe': Unloaded
>   'C:\SomePath\Build\Eddy\Debug\SomeDLL.dll'
>   'MyApp.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\SomePath\Build\Eddy\Debug\SomeDLL.dll'
>   'MyApp.exe': Unloaded
>   'C:\SomePath\Build\Eddy\Debug\SomeDLL.dll'

And I the get the following error dialog:

> Unable to load DLL 'SomeDLL.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The code in question works fine on my colleagues windows XP machine. There's also another C++ DLL in the solution which works fine.

Comment: As you have marked it Windows 7 - 64 bit, is it possible that your dll may be 32-bit specific or it may have dependency on a 32 bit dll. You can try building your project for x86 platform and check if the error goes away (just to see if its the issue with 32-bit/64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that SomeDll.dll cannot be loaded. There are a few different reasons for why this may happen and some of them are:

1. The dll is 32-bit and you are running a 64-bit process (or the other way around).
2. SomeDLL.dll has some additional dependencies (other dll:s or COM components) that are not available.

You can run Dependeny Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ on your somedll.dll to see if it is point 2 that is the problem.

Comment: The non working DLL had dependencies to some other DLLs, when I copied these into the working directory of my C# project everything worked fine.